# How to tell if an instance is of a certain Type or any derived types

Tags: c#, casting, types

I'm trying to write a validation to check that an Object instance can be cast to a variable Type. I have a Type instance for the type of object they need to provide. But the Type can vary. This is basically what I want to do.

```
        Object obj = new object();
        Type typ = typeof(string); //just a sample, really typ is a variable

        if(obj is typ) //this is wrong "is" does not work like this
        {
            //do something
        }
```

The type object itself has the IsSubClassOf, and IsInstanceOfType methods. But what I really want to check is if **obj** is either an instance of **typ** or any class derived from **typ**.

Seems like a simple question, but I can't seem to figure it out.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

How about this:

```
    MyObject myObject = new MyObject();
    Type type = myObject.GetType();

    if(typeof(YourBaseObject).IsAssignableFrom(type))
    {  
       //Do your casting.
       YourBaseObject baseobject = (YourBaseObject)myObject;
    }
```

This tells you if that object can be casted to that certain type.

Comment: Yeah I found that later last night. Thanks though.

Answer (score 7):

I think you need to restate your conditions, because if `obj` is an instance of `Derived`, it will also be an instance of `Base`. And `typ.IsIstanceOfType(obj)` will return true.

```
class Base { }
class Derived : Base { }

object obj = new Derived();
Type typ = typeof(Base);

type.IsInstanceOfType(obj); // = true
type.IsAssignableFrom(obj.GetType()); // = true
```

Answer (score 6):

If you are working with Instances, you should be going for [Type.IsInstanceOfType](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.type.isinstanceoftype.aspx)

> (Returns) true if the current Type is
>   in the inheritance hierarchy of the
>   object represented by o, or if the
>   current Type is an interface that o
>   supports. false if neither of these
>   conditions is the case, or if o is
>   nullNothingnullptra null reference
>   (Nothing in Visual Basic), or if the
>   current Type is an open generic type
>   (that is, ContainsGenericParameters
>   returns true). -- MSDN

```
        Base b = new Base();
        Derived d = new Derived();
        if (typeof(Base).IsInstanceOfType(b)) 
            Console.WriteLine("b can come in.");    // will be printed
        if (typeof(Base).IsInstanceOfType(d)) 
            Console.WriteLine("d can come in.");    // will be printed
```

If you are working with Type objects, then you should look at [Type.IsAssignableFrom](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.type.isassignablefrom.aspx)

> (Returns) true if c and the current Type
>   represent the same type, or if the
>   current Type is in the inheritance
>   hierarchy of c, or if the current Type
>   is an interface that c implements, or
>   if c is a generic type parameter and
>   the current Type represents one of the
>   constraints of c. false if none of
>   these conditions are true, or if c is
>   nullNothingnullptra null reference
>   (Nothing in Visual Basic). -- MSDN